# How to refresh webpage after clicking on “Update” in Grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an Asp.net, C# Application.
I want to Refresh the webpage after I clicking on “Update” LinkButton; in Grid view. I have tried the following code; however it just refreshes the page without saving the updated data in Grid view.

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.ToString());
}
```

Name of DataSource `SqlDataSourcePlan`

```
SELECT [PlanID], [Deposit], [DepositReturn], [Discount] FROM [PaymentPlan] WHERE ([Ref] = @Ref)

UPDATE [PaymentPlan] SET [Deposit] = @Deposit, [DepositReturn] = @DepositReturn, [Discount] = @Discount WHERE [PlanID] = @original_PlanID
```

Comment: How you tried to debug your code to find out that in the PageLoad method the loading of the information in the page occurs? What is your datasource for your gridview?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`RawUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.rawurl.aspx) instead:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

> The raw URL is defined as the part of the URL following the domain
>   information. In the URL string
>   http://www.contoso.com/articles/recent.aspx, the raw URL is
>   /articles/recent.aspx. The raw URL includes the query string, if
>   present.

**Edit**: *"without saving the updated data in Grid view"*

Why do you think that redirecting the page to itself should save something somewhere?

Have a look at this tutorial: [Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data with the SqlDataSource (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs)

I assume that you actually want to  **update the GridView** instead of the whole page. Then you should call `GridView.DataBind()`.

Comment: Sorry but it didn’t fix the issue; nevertheless thanks it was a GOOD Tip; I have changed the code to “Request.RawUrl”

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at this tutorial which explains it all:  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs

Comment: Yes Sir I have Looked at these tutorial and they do help me update data however, I need to refresh the page after update.
You have raised a good point;
“Why do you think that redirecting the page to itself should save something somewhere?”
 So how do you think I should Approach this.
Thanks

Comment: @Zee-pro: I assume is that you actually want to _update the GridView_ instead of the whole page. Then you should call `GridView.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (without some other informations in the code it is difficult to say) is that althought the information is saved in the database, the `datasource` for the `gridview` is not refreshed with the new values. 
I have seen this problem often regarding this part.

You have to rebind the gridview with `Page.DataBind` or `GridViewName.DataBind()` (where `GridViewName` is the name of your `gridview`) before the redirect.

You probably don't reload the GridView at `PageLoad` or `PageLoad` does not occure (can't know without the server code). If that would work properly, you would not need the databinding before redirecting.